# Do Dyck Words or Dyck Paths Have Manifestations in Nature?

Tags: formal-languages, applications

Working with the Dyck language of well-balanced strings of parentheses, I am led to wonder what, if any, phenomena the concept relates to in the natural world - in the same sense that Fibonacci numbers, for example, have manifestations as patterns in sunflower floret spirals.

Since Dyck words have equivalent Dyck paths, I also included the latter in my question.

I hope this is an appropriate board to ask such a question; if you can suggest a better place, I'll be happy to go there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a page in the presentation of the Vancouver (B.C., Canada) science museum [Science World](https://www.scienceworld.ca/stories/patterns-nature-finding-fractals/#:%7E:text=A%20fractal%20is%20a%20kind,whole%2C%20that%27s%20a%20fractal.%E2%80%9D):

> A fractal is a kind of pattern that we observe often in nature and in art. As Ben Weiss explains, “whenever you observe a series of patterns repeating over and over again, at many different scales, and where any small part resembles the whole, that’s a fractal.”

Not only is it a fractal. It's also a Dyck language, since a Dyck language is an abstraction of precisely the recursive structure described in that paragraph.

Comment: Interesting observation, @rici.  In particular, the article mentions Lichtenberg figures, the branching tree-like patterns seen in insulators after an electrical discharge.  I'm able to see how they, as well as forking patterns such as those observed in aerial views of river systems and in the bronchial airways of lungs, can be described by words in a Dyck language.